# What does msgSender() this code do in the OpenSea repository's example ERC721?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, opensea

```
abstract contract ContextMixin {
    function msgSender()
        internal
        view
        returns (address payable sender)
    {
        if (msg.sender == address(this)) {
            bytes memory array = msg.data;
            uint256 index = msg.data.length;
            assembly {
                // Load the 32 bytes word from memory with the address on the lower 20 bytes, and mask those.
                sender := and(
                    mload(add(array, index)),
                    0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
                )
            }
        } else {
            sender = payable(msg.sender);
        }
        return sender;
    }
}
```

Is this a OpenSea specific thing or in general?

Comment: Think it's just a wrapper for msg.sender. OpenZeppelin has one for its Context smart contracts as well. From what I understand, it's useful in cases where you want msg.sender in some cases, but want some other address in others.

Comment: @SlothMan I understand this exists so that OpenSea code can call my code and pretend to be me, I want to understand if this is a common standard?

Comment: Common standard as in common practice? Then yes, I think it is. Context smart contracts with wrapper functions for msg.sender is often used. It provides an alternative to calling tx.origin, which is generally accepted to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's supposed to be used for meta-transactions. You can find similar examples that OpenZeppelin implemented that was also designed to be used this way.

To support native meta transaction, OpenSea inherits from the `NativeMetaTransaction` contract that executes another function on itself (on behalf of the user with a signature), which will make the `msg.sender` its own address (`address(this)`).

(Read this if you don't understand why msg.sender can be the contract address itself: [How can msg.sender == address(this)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99677/how-can-msg-sender-addressthis) )

In OpenSea's case, the meta transaction is executed by the function [`executeMetaTransaction` here](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/f7257a043e82fae8251eec2bdde37a44fee474c4/contracts/common/meta-transactions/NativeMetaTransaction.sol#L33), which put the user's address as the first argument. So the `_msgSender()` function is basically just saying, if this is a meta transaction, use the original signer's (user) address as the message sender, which can be found by parsing  `msg.data`.

This is how they can support some gas-less transactions, where you just need to sign a signature and the OpenSea proxy will pay gas for you, while the contract will just work as you're interacting with it directly, without introducing additional roles in the contracts.